# Are cookies ever returned with spaces in them?

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies

[This MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#Example_.232.3A_Get_a_sample_cookie_named_test2) article suggests the following code for extracting cookies:

```
document.cookie = "test1=Hello";
document.cookie = "test2=World";

var myCookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)test2\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

alert(myCookie);
// displays: World
```

However the regex looks to me to have pointless whitespace specifiers. I tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE and they all responded with the cookies in the form of `one=two; three=four` with a single space between each cookie and none around the equals.

Couldn't the regex be simply put as put as `/(?:(?:^|.*;\s)test2=([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/`?
(Though I would have the text selection as `[^;]+` personally)

Comment: Why not? If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Another rule of software engineering and building: "Adhere to standards to the outside, but don't expect anyone else to."